# About animation in android widget

Tags: android, animation, widget

I want move widget (such as button) with animation described in XML.
But after animation done, that widget return first position.
How can I stop widget where I want position.

Comment: I have encountered this exact same issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animation only describes the movement of the widget, and when the animation finishes the widget is redrawn at its original location.

You need to move the widget to the final location immediately before you animate it. Then when the animation is finished the widget new position will be the same as its position at the end of the animation.

Comment: Is there any another ways? Something like change a property etc.

Comment: Why would there be another way? The animation only moves the widget during the animation. When the animation is finished its over the view is no longer moved. You have to move it yourself.